# Listening on a specific port for incoming data

Tags: android, connection, wifi, port, broadcast

In order to scan a WiFi network for other devices, I send a broadcast with my application a a specific port to all IPs in the WiFi network.
Therefore the application, if it's running on a device in the WiFi network, has to respond to this broadcast.

At first I send a DatagramPacket with some data in it. Then the listening device has to listen on a port for this DatagramPacket and send it back with its own device IP.

How do I manage this?

Comment: hello, did you find a solution for this please ?